# TFS 2018 Server Setup

Tags: tfs

I have been trying to configure TFS 2018 on my local machine. its installing and i am able to open tfs url in my browser.

while configuring the application tier, default collection is not being created successfully.

it throws warning in log:

```
**Queued project collection creation for host: 57cd339d-cdef-48e5-b049-b80de4949dd2
[Info   @13:00:26.567] Waiting for servicing. Host: 57cd339d-cdef-48e5-b049-b80de4949dd2. JobId: 03c49056-b761-441b-a543-dbe986a45248
[Info   @13:10:57.046] TF255269: The following team project collection is being created: 57cd339d-cdef-48e5-b049-b80de4949dd2.
[Info   @13:11:02.048] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:02.048] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:07.051] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:07.051] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:12.054] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:12.054] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:17.057] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:17.057] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:22.059] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:22.059] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:27.061] details: 0
[Info   @13:11:27.061] pseudo ops(*)?False
[Info   @13:11:27.061] TF255269: The following team project collection is being created: 57cd339d-cdef-48e5-b049-b80de4949dd2.
[Warning@13:11:27.063] TF255270: The following team project collection could not be created because the process timed out: (57cd339d-cdef-48e5-b049-b80de4949dd2).
[Warning@13:11:27.064] TF255271: The team project collection could not be created. The number of steps before the completion of project creation is: -1. The number of steps completed before the failure was 0.
[Info   @13:11:27.085] Node returned: Error
[Warning@13:11:27.087] There was a problem or delay during the creation of your initial Team Project Collection. To check the status of the Team Project Collection, launch the Team Foundation Administration Console and review the current status on the Team Project Collection node.
You must create at least one team project collection before you can use the features of Team Foundation Server. You can create a team project collection by using the New Team Project Collection Wizard from the Team Foundation Administration Console.**
```

Collection shows (Creating...) and is offline. even if i am trying to create new collection its same situation.
[While creating new collection it gets stuck as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcI0b.png) &&
[Collections offline as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDcor.png)
Please help if anyone has solved this and fixed this.

Comment: Why are you installing TFS on your local machine?

Comment: wanted to do one POC for tfs to vsts migration

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall